# Radzen blazor HTML Editor can’t save large text C#

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, html-editor

Large text (more than 5000 words or more) can't save through Radzen HTML editor, I'm getting below error. please have a look error below

```
Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error.'.
```

Code Below:

```
<RadzenHtmlEditor Style="height: 250px; margin-bottom: 1rem;"
                          @bind-Value="@Value"
                          Disabled="@IsSaving"
                          Change="@(OnChange)" />

 private async Task OnChange(string selectedValue) // selectedValue coming null for large text but for small text like 2000 words is fine.
        {
            try {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PropertyName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
                    return;
// Do stuff
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```

[image]

**How I can resolve this issue? Its a blazor server side application.** Thanks !

Comment: That error says the server crashed, not the Radzen editor. `catch (Exception e){}` is a terrible idea that hides problems that can easily cause a crash further on. Right now it's impossible to say what's wrong because there's no exception or actual code

Comment: catch (Exception e)
            {
            } I'm trying to catch the error but cursor is not coming in catch function.  OnChange(string selectedValue) // here value is coming null. There have any setting things that can allow large text ? Thanks !

Comment: This has nothing to do with large text. 5K words is a *small* amount of text. Your application crashed. Did you check its logs? Have you configured logging in the first place? `Attempting to reconnect to the server` means the server has crashed and the client code can't talk to it

Comment: I'm getting only this log "Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error" . Thanks !

Comment: That's not an exception. If your application crashes the exception error will be written to the console and the log. Even if there's no log file configured, you can run your application from the command line and read the messages written to the console

Comment: I have increased the size for Singal R and that fixed the issue now. or have you any good solutions ?

    services.AddSignalR(e => {
                    e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
                });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have increased the size for Singal R and that fixed the issue now. or have you any good solutions ?

```
services.AddSignalR(e => {
                e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
            });
```